# Trickle Charge Car Battery / Car GND versus Negative Terminal on Battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics

I have a few cars that don't get driven in the winter, and I am going to keep hooked up to a trickle charger to charge / maintain the 12V lead acid batteries.

In reviewing the trickle charger documentation and the internets, supposedly you should hook up the trickle charger positive to the battery positive and then you should hook up the battery charger negative to some GND source of the car (instead of the battery negative terminal).

In every embedded system I've ever seen, the battery charging IC runs directly to the positive terminal and negative terminal on the battery.

What gives?   Anyone have any idea what the actual reason you would a separate car GND to charge the battery versus just using the positive and negative terminal on the battery?

Comment: They do that to avoid a spark occurring near the battery.   As batteries discharge, they release hydrogen gas.   Modern batteries not so much as older ones, but they do (this is the source of the green corrosion you find on the terminals occasionally, not 'leaking acid').     By making the last connection far away from the battery, the odds of igniting the hydrogen and blowing up the battery go from 'very very very unlikely' to 'almost zero'.  This is the same way you're supposed to connect jumper cables BTW.    "Electrically", you're right, the two setups are identical.

Comment: While it is 'very very very unlikely', in all my years I did witness one battery explode.  The driver kept wiggling terminals and trying to start his car. 5th time, it exploded, spraying acid onto the front of a convenience store (high school bus stop) and onto a few people nearby (students.)  With some quick-thinking water from inside, nobody was injured.

Comment: Crazy.   I have two Porsches waiting to explode in my garage. ;)

Comment: @rdtsc  Wow!   OK - I'm gonna rephrase it to just "very unlikely" !!   (Deleted two 'very's  LOL)   Amazing nobody got it in their eyes - the outcome woulda been WAY worse!   One time I was helping some stranded ladies with their car (had overheated) -- I just pushed the radiator hose with my finger a little, hot antifreeze blew out a hole and got one of 'em in the eye.  I felt terrible.   I think she was OK, but I never saw them again  (I did manage to patch the hose well enough to get them home though)